# How to dynamically apply multiple with statements

Tags: python, contextmanager

How to generate nested with statements? Example:

```
with patch.object(getattr("module1", "cls1"), "foo"):
  with patch.object(getattr("module2", "cls2"), "foo"):
    with patch.object(getattr("module3", "cls3"), "foo"):
      # do something
```

If I have a list of items which needs to be put in the nested `with` statements, e.g.

`list=[("module1", "cls1"), ("module2", "cls2"), ("module3", "cls3")]`

how can I simulate the above code?

Comment: So, is your question actually "How can I have several dynamic context managers"? In this case, "generate the code" would be misleading, as it could be understood as "I want code that will write this source code for me". Or is it really what you mean?

Comment: I don’t want to write this source code, I want to dynamically apply several context managers as shown in an example. 'Generate' was not the best word choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like task for [`contextlib.ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack), following example is given in docs

```
with ExitStack() as stack:
    files = [stack.enter_context(open(fname)) for fname in filenames]
    # All opened files will automatically be closed at the end of
    # the with statement, even if attempts to open files later
    # in the list raise an exception
```

Comment: This is just a copy from the official docs. It would improve the understanding if you could serve code in your answer that fits better to the questioners example. Show us a real world case.

Comment: Thank you, this is working. The code for my question should be 
```
 with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
  for module, cls in list:
    stack.enter_context(patch.object(getattr(module, cls), "foo"))
```